# Is there a better way to repeat chained jQuery methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I repeat `.last().text()` a lot (see below). Is there a way I can do this more efficiently so my code doesn't look so wordy?  Is it possible to store `.last().text()` in a variable?  I'm a newbie (obvs).

```
$("div").last().text(`${date} `).append("<span class = 'username'></span><span class = 'text'></span>");
$(".username").last().text(`${message.username}`);
$(".text").last().text(` ${message.text}`);
```

Comment: `const fn=(q,t)=>$(q).last().text(t)` - use: `fn('div', \`${date} \`). ....`

Comment: to be fair, even with the function (as in the comment and the answer below) it does not look any "less wordy"

Comment: @JaromandaX, at least it is DRY ;)

Comment: a little drier, sure :p

Answer (score 2):

Put it in a function

```
const setTextToLastOf = (selector, text) => {
    return $(selector).last().text(text);
}
```

Then use it

```
const appendText = "<span class = 'username'></span><span class = 'text'></span>";
setTextToLastOf("div", `${date} `).append(appendText);
setTextToLastOf(".username", `${message.username}`);
setTextToLastOf(".text", ` ${message.text}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can create your own jQuery function.

In the below snippet you can see how to define a `lastText()` function for jQuery.

*Updated the answer so you can set the last text too.*

If you set a text the jQuery object (`this`) is returned so you can keep chaining functions on it. If you get the text the function returns a string with the text of the last element.

```js
jQuery.fn.lastText = function(text) {
    if(text == null) {
        return this.last().text();
    }
    else {
        return this.last().text(text);
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  var currLastText = $('.par').lastText();
  console.log("current last text: " + currLastText );
  var newLastText = $('.par').lastText("Last").lastText();
  console.log("New last text: " + newLastText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="par">First</p>
<p class="par">Second</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to make it less messy is to use the `:last` selector:

```
$("div:last").text(`${date} `).append("<span class = 'username'></span><span class = 'text'></span>");
$(".username:last").text(`${message.username}`);
$(".text:last").text(` ${message.text}`);
```